# Add several fields into an array containing objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update an object into an array in MongoDB.
Here are my documents :

```js
> db.devis.insert({id:1,obj:[{'code':'A'},{'code':'B'}]})  
> db.devis.insert({id:2,obj:[{'code':'C'},{'code':'D'}]})  

> db.devis.find()
[
  {
    id: 1,
    obj: [ { code: 'A' }, { code: 'B' } ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    obj: [ { code: 'C'}, { code: 'D' } ]
  }
]
```

I select the document with the code 'B'.
I can add one field with this command :

```js
> db.devis.update({'obj.code':'B'},{$set: {'obj.$.a':'a'}})  

# Result
{
  id: 1,
  obj: [ { code: 'A'}, { code: 'B', a: 'a'} ]
}
```

Now I want to add several fields :

```js
> var = {'foo':'foo', 'bar':'bar'}
> db.devis.update({'obj.code':'B'},{$set: {'obj.$': var}})

# Result
{
  id: 1,
  obj: [ { code: 'A'}, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'} ]
}

# What I want
{
  id: 1,
  obj: [ { code: 'A'}, { code: 'B', foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'} ]
}
```

The object is overwritten.
It is possible to insert in it several fields from a variable ?

Comment: Clarity:  You want to keep `code` but get rid of `a` and add `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: No the `a` was just an example to add one field,  @J.F. answered exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are seting the entire object.

When you do `{$set: {obj.$:{yourObject}}}` you are telling mongo: "Set entire object `obj` as the object I have passed".

Look at this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wQEBGayPtKa)

The object with `code : B` is completly new because your `$` operator point at the object and `$set` will put the new object at this position.

You need this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "obj.code": "B"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "obj.$.foo": "bar",
    "obj.$.foo2": "bar2"
  }
})
```

In this case, your `$set` uses the `$` operator to update the field into the object, no the object itself.
In this way you are telling mongo: "Put into the object you have found a variable called 'foo' with value 'bar' and another variable 'foo2' with value 'bar2'"

I hope I have explained well to note the difference between the two queries.

So, no tested, but using:

```js
var = {'obj.$.foo':'foo', 'obj.$.bar':'bar'}
db.devis.update({'obj.code':'B'},{$set: var})
```

Should works.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iLWltGQ7qoU)